# ACCESS DB Backend - Invoice numbers and locking table with C# WPF

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I am in the process of rewriting the front end of a legacy app, used for Automotive Spare parts. The system is a multi-user environment wit split databases and using MSACCESS MDB file type.

The system generates invoices for which I need to ensure are unique ids for each invoice, this Table is simple [Autonumber, Date, invoice_no] when a new record is created the invoice no is based on the Autonumber, padded with zeros ie (most recent invoice number/record + 1) . This number is then used elsewhere (registerhistory) to maintain a relationship between individual transactions and the invoice itself.

This was fine in ADO recordset and jet I could use pessimistic locking, ensuring that unique numbers were obtained, and multiuser attempts always resulted in

I am using the ACE.OLEDB provider recordset atm but cannot find an equivalent locking mechanism to ensure this workflow (this is flexible to achieve desired outcome)

```
NEW INVOICE
Lock table 
Get Invoice Number (most recent invnumber +1)
Add new invoice number
Unlock Table
END
```

This is the idea I am trying by using a transaction and setting an isolation level but I am getting "Neither the isolation level nor a strengthening of it is supported."

Can anyone provide some insight or recommendations - YES it will be migrated to SQL server, with some data conversion etc ATM this is not possible as the front end dev needs to be completed, whilst the old front end is still operational with the existing database.

```
public void getDocketNumber()
{
    connectionString = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = 
    C:\Register\SourceCode\DataBase\Medicar.mdb;";
       
    OleDbConnection DBConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

    DBConnection.Open();
    DBConnection.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead);
        
}
```

Comment: I recommend using LocalDB on that front end work to ensure a seamless transition to SQL Server. `SqlClient` can be used for both instead of dealing with OLEDB for any amount of time. And all the problems you've had with OLEDB go out the window.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with LocalDB can you elaborate (apologies for my ignorance) - the existing legacy front end is VB6 and I am going towards WPF for new front end.

Comment: LocalDB is a development installation of SQL Server. Google it.  You probably already have it installed.

Comment: You can't base the new invoice number on both the autonumber and the last used number+1. Make your choice.

Comment: I am in a position where the new front end has to rollout and be utilised due to ever failing support and compatibility of the old front end with newer operating systems. Unfortunately I have to achieve the lock on the Access DB backend table, update exclusively and then use this number. But definitely use localDB in the sql migration phase.

Comment: Probably not worth using LocalDB that late in the game. Go straight to a full SQL Server instance.

Comment: Thanks Gustav yes it will only be the Autonumber, but I still need mechanism to ensure that the last most recent autonumber is unique when querying the (max)

Comment: I think there's a major drawback in your approach to replacing the system. You're trying to build an application that connects to the same old database, and then later change to a different database. That incurs the additional development of having to rewrite the database access twice. Your data is sacred, so start by designing a new database in SQL Server, and ensure that you can migrate your data perfectly. Then write a new application to use it. Do a final data migration before cutting over to the new application.

Comment: I have implemented Data Access Layers for each of the tables that I have to use, these have been coded using SQL statements that are are piped to the MDB backend, I have thought about my migration path to SQL in this regard. The problem is that the business still needs to function, the existing VB6 front end is buggy. I am in the position, recreate an sql backend that works with the existing front end whilst the user still use the frontend with fading support and resources, or develop a new front end addressing the existing bugs, maintaining some data integrity. Then xfer data to SQL

Comment: I get the input so far but all I need to do is lock the table very briefly to obtain a new invoice number, so far my searches have come up short, just needed some modern implementation of adlockpessimistic - so far I have found nothing